# Why is this returning an address in the console?

Tags: c++, ostringstream, istringstream, sstream

I'm trying to wrap my head around ostringstreams and istringstreams. So, as I always do, I made a log-in program out of it. but every time I try to cout the contents of the username and password variables, it returns the address!

Purpose for program: to create a simulated log-in screen using input and output stringstreams

code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char *argc[]){

char ch;
ostringstream username,
    password;
ostringstream *uptr, 
    *pptr;

uptr = &username;
pptr = &password;

cout << "Welcome" << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter a username: ";
do{

    ch = _getch();
    *uptr << ch;
    cout << ch;

}while(ch != '\r');


cout << endl << "Enter a Password: ";
do{
    ch = _getch();
    *pptr << ch;
    cout << "*";

}while(ch != '\r');

//if(username == "graywolfmedia25@gmail.com" && password == "deadbeefcoffee10031995"){
    cout << endl << "username: " << *username << endl << "password: " << *password << endl;
//} else {
    //cout << endl << "ACCESS DENIED" << endl;
//}



return 0;
}
```

I tried using the *uptr and *pptr last, but before that I tried just writing and reading straight from the variables.

Comment: i have no idea what you are doing, but try `username.str()`

Comment: @BryanChen you are a beautiful person XD thank you for the help. and sorry for the unclear code.. i'm working on it :P can you explain the .str() class? or link me to a good resource that will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [`str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/str/) to get `std::string` from [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/)

so

```
cout << endl << "username: " << username.str() << endl << "password: " << password.str() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard streams have output operators for addresses: when you try to print a pointer, it will just print the pointer's address. In addition, the streams have a conversion to pointer which used to indicate if the stream is in a good state: when it is in good state, i.e., `stream.fail() == false`, it converts to a suitable non-null pointer, normally just `this`. When it is in failure state it return `0` (the reason it isn't converting to `bool` is to avoid, e.g., `std::cout >> i` to be valid: if it would convert to `bool` this code would be valid).

Assuming you want to print the content of the string stream, you'd just use `stream.str()` to get the stream's `std::string`.